# Changing the onClickListener of an Imagebutton dynamically without ever leaving the activity

Tags: java, android

I have an `ImageButton` with an `onClickListener`. That sets the "favorite" column of an entry in my database to "1" or "0" and changes the image of the button. What is the best way to refresh the view or activity, so the `onClickListener` changes dynamically.

If I failed to make myself clear:

- Click 1: Update favorite column to 1, change image to `ic_star_black_48dp`
- Click 2: Update favorite column to 0, change image to `ic_star_border_black_48dp`
- Click 3: Update favorite column to 1, change image to `ic_star_black_48dp`
- Click 4: Update favorite column to 0, change image to `ic_star_border_black_48dp`

All of this without ever leaving the activity.

```
 star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cn.getFavorite() == 0) {
                star.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_star_black_48dp);
                db_verladestellen.updatePlace(new Location(cn.getID(), cn.getPlace_id(), cn.getName(), cn.getLongitude(), cn.getLatitude(), cn.getTor(), 1));
            }
            else{
                star.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_star_border_black_48dp);
                db_verladestellen.updatePlace(new Location(cn.getID(), cn.getPlace_id(), cn.getName(), cn.getLongitude(), cn.getLatitude(), cn.getTor(), 0));
            }
        }

    });
```

EDIT:

Since you asked, this is the whole class. Below it is the method `getAllDBPlaces()`.

```
public class UI_Verladestellen extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verladestellen);

        //Initialisation of the database
        final DB_Verladestellen db_verladestellen = new DB_Verladestellen(this);

        //Saves all entries from the database in a List
        List<Location> placeList = db_verladestellen.getAllDBPlaces();


        //Generates a button for each entry in the list
        for (final Location cn : placeList) {

            //Linear Layout for the buttons
            final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.verladestellen_liste);
            final LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            //Favorites-Button
            final ImageButton star = new ImageButton(this);
            star.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            if (cn.getFavorite() == 0) {star.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_star_border_black_48dp);}
            else {star.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_star_black_48dp);}
            star.setId(cn.getID());
            row.addView(star);
            star.setPadding(50,50,50,50);
            star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (cn.getFavorite() == 0) {
                        star.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_star_black_48dp);
                        db_verladestellen.updatePlace(new Location(cn.getID(), cn.getPlace_id(), cn.getName(), cn.getLongitude(), cn.getLatitude(), cn.getTor(), 1));
                    }
                    else{
                        star.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_star_border_black_48dp);
                        db_verladestellen.updatePlace(new Location(cn.getID(), cn.getPlace_id(), cn.getName(), cn.getLongitude(), cn.getLatitude(), cn.getTor(), 0));
                    }
                }
            });

            //Location-Button
            Button place = new Button(this);
            place.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            place.setText(cn.getName());
            place.setId(cn.getID());
            row.addView(place);
            row.setId(cn.getID());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) place.getLayoutParams();
            params.weight = 1.0f;
            place.setLayoutParams(params);
            place.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openMap(cn.getID());
                }
            });

            layout.addView(row);
        }
    }

    //Methode zum öffnen der Map in MainActivity. Übermittelt die ID des Buttons, von dem die Methode aufgerufen wird.
    //Diese ID ist identisch mit der ID des Ortes in der Datenbank, den der Button repräsentiert.
    public void openMap(int view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UI_Verladestellen.this, UI_MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("findLocation", view);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

getALLDBPlaces:

```
public List<Location> getAllDBPlaces() {
    List<Location> placeList = new ArrayList<Location>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DB_VERLADESTELLEN_Eintrag;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Location location = new Location();
            location.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            location.setPlace_id(cursor.getString(1));
            location.setName(cursor.getString(2));
            location.setLongitude(cursor.getString(3));
            location.setLatitude(cursor.getString(4));
            location.setTor(cursor.getString(5));
            location.setFavorite(cursor.getInt(6));
            // Adding contact to list
            placeList.add(location);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return contact list
    return placeList;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code ?

Comment: @Anto nothing is wrong with it. Thats the code as it is. Now I want to know where I need to put what, so it behaves like I described.

Comment: This looks correct and should do what you need (by only seeing this part of your code)

Comment: BTW, mipmap should only be used for your application icone :)

Comment: you are using cn.getFavorite(), but never setting the new value. Or maybe show your getFavorite() method !

Comment: No it does not. If I click the button it sets favorite to 1 and changes the image to `ic_star_black_48dp`. If I click it again it sets favorite to 1 and changes the image to `ic_star_black_48dp`. If I click it again it sets favorite to 1 and changes the image to `ic_star_black_48dp`. Do you see what I mean. If i would have a way to refresh the view or the activity, the if-statement would be checked again (it checks if favorite is 1 or 0), so the onclicklistener would automatically change with it.

Comment: `cn.getFavorite()` checks the database for the value in "favorite" of the exact same entry I update with the button.

Comment: Well each time you click you are forcing favorite to 1 !? in your first case you should set it to 1, in the else, set it to 0 !

Comment: ok. Are you sure the row are correctly updated ? because your code should work, Unless your getFavorite() is wrong or the way you update db

Comment: I am not sure you understand what I want. My code works, yes, but only if I leave the activity, and come back to it again. Because the if statement, that decides what my onclicklistener should do, is only handled when the activity is created. But I want it to work, without leaving the activity. So I need a way, to refresh the activity, so the if-statement gets handled again and the onclick listener changes.

Comment: see my answer. and tell me where you init cn variable

Answer (score 0):

Well after you edited your question, my answer will be different.
First of all, you should check for Adapter implementation.
It will be easier to handle your scenario and be way more effective.
But then you should try to implement it yourself and come agian if you face any issues.

Comment: I posted an answer myself now. Look at it and you know what I meant.

Comment: Ok, your implementation is quiet incorrect, you should use an Adapter. This will help a lot to do what you need in a simplier and effectiveness way. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html